# Watching for changes in dynamically changing objects in vuejs

Tags: javascript, regex, object, vue.js, watch

I am trying to watch for changes in the "item.amount" v-model and add commas to it after every thousand. Problem is the v-model is an object item and thus I cannot access it directly using the watch method. My code is shown below:

```
<div class="row" v-for="(item,index) in Payments" :key="index">
  <input type="text" v-model="item.amount" placeholder="Amount" class="typeahead form-control-sm">
  <input class="typeahead form-control-sm" type="number" placeholder="Destination number" max="9999999999" min="0" onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==10 && event.keyCode>47 && event.keyCode < 58)return false;" v-model="item.Number" />
</div>
```

**How can I possibly watch for changes in item.amount so I can format the output as the user inputs the amount** by using something like `String(item.amount).replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");`

Comment: You need to use a "key" event if you want to account for each keystroke: keyup, keydown, etc.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Thanks for this reply. Could you provide a codepen link to further explain your point because I tried using the keyup event but it only worked for the first input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to watch the changes by handling `@input` event by the method `onType` which take the `index` of the current item and change it in `Payments` array

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    Payments: [{
        "amount": 1122

      },
      {
        "amount": 8852

      },
      {
        "amount": 75553

      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    onType(i) {
      this.Payments[i].amount = String(this.Payments[i].amount).replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.Payments.length; i++)
      this.onType(i)
  }

})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Vue.delete">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="row" v-for="(item,index) in Payments" :key="index">
      <input type="text" v-model="item.amount" @input="onType(index)" placeholder="Amount" class="typeahead form-control-sm">
      <input class="typeahead form-control-sm" type="number" placeholder="Destination number" max="9999999999" min="0" onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==10 && event.keyCode>47 && event.keyCode < 58)return false;" v-model="item.Number" />
    </div>
```

**EDIT**

The values could be changed in the mounted hook if the inputs are pre-filled

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the formatting in a method. I.e,

```
methods: {
  formatNumber: function(x){
    String(x).replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }
}
```

And output it like this;

```
{{formatNumber(item.amount)}}
```

Or;

```
:value="formatNumber(item.amount)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I'm trying to do is to format the number as the user is typing in the input box. The :value and the function methods are not working for me